# How to resolve getting an error on thymeleaf onclick

Tags: thymeleaf

I am getting an error on thymeleaf onclick.

```
<a th:text="${list.id}" th:href="@{/adm/page/testList/{id}(id=${list.id})}"></a>
```

I want to replace this code with:

```
<a th:onclick="'window.location.href = \'' + @{/adm/page/testList/{id}(id=${list.id})} + '\''"></ a>
```

But the `@{` gets a red line.

I am wondering how to solve this error.

Comment: What exact error do you get with the original `th:href="@{/adm/page/testList/{id}(id=${list.id})}"` ? Because that should work normally.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code can help you:

```
<a th:onclick="window.location.href = '/adm/page/testList/[[${list.id}]]'"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data properties, you can do syntax like this (which should be valid).

```
<a th:text="${list.id}" th:data-url="@{/adm/page/testList/{id}(id=${list.id})}" onclick="window.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-url');"></a>
```